# Definability of a function obtained by the mean value theorem (o-minimal setting)

Tags: first-order-logic, model-theory

Let $\mathcal{R}$ an o-minimal expansion of $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ and $g$ a unary definable function such that $g'\sim 1/x$ (by the monotonicity theorem $g$ is ultimately differentiable)

By applying the mean value theorem on $g$ (by the monotonicity theorem $g$ is ultimately differentiable) there exists a function $f$ ultimatly defined such that $$g(2x)-g(x)=x\cdot g'(f(x))$$

**My question :** Why is f definable?

**My argument :** By applying the monotonicity theorem on $g'$ (the derivative of a definable function is definable) $g'$ is either constant or strictly monotone. By the assumption $g'\sim 1/x$ , $g'$ cant be a constant. hence $(g')^{-1}$ is ultimately defined. thus we have ultimatly $$(g')^{-1}(\frac{g(2x)-g(x)}{x})=f(x)$$

Hence $f$ is definable as compsition of definable functions.

Is my argument good?